# Android ACRA and ProGuard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, proguard

On ACRA website there is a guide about use of ACRA and ProGuard with Eclipse: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/ProGuard

In my case I use Android Studio and I'm not expert about java, however I need add the ACRA support to my app. I just have edit my project but I don't understand how can I set ProGuard inside Android Studio to work with ACRA so in my release app ACRA doesn't work.

Can you explane with "convert" Eclipse steps to Android Studio steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an existing eclipse project and wanted to import it in Android Studio?

if not here is the solution:

Your build.gradle(the one is in "app" folder) file should look something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true//make this true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'//add this line here
}
```

and your proguard-rules.pro:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Android\AndroidSDKBundle2014-03-21x64\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
#class:
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}


#ACRA specifics
# Restore some Source file names and restore approximate line numbers in the stack traces,
# otherwise the stack traces are pretty useless
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this...
# Note: This may already be defined in the default "proguard-android-optimize.txt"
# file in the SDK. If it is, then you don't need to duplicate it. See your
# "project.properties" file to get the path to the default "proguard-android-optimize.txt".
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter {
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter {
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

the rest is like the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Studio project should have a `proguard-rules.txt` file. You need to add a few directives to this file to tell ProGuard what to preserve, drawing upon the ProGuard directives in the ACRA instructions.

Mostly, you'll copy the contents of ACRA's `proguard-project.txt` into you're project's `proguard-rules.txt` file.

You might have to add some directives that the ACRA instructions expected to be in Eclipse's ProGuard config base file `proguard-android-optimize.txt` where that file differs from Android Studio's file `android-studio\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android-optimize.txt`

An example directive from `proguard-android-optimize.txt`:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

This tells ProGuard to keep every class that has a native method.